# Spring Boot Servlet API Version

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot app on Tomcat 7. From my understanding, it should be compatible with servlet 3.0 spec.

In my dependency, I mark tomcat as provided:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope> <!-- Mark as provided so it doesn't interfere when we deploy in container -->
</dependency>
```

Edit: And I've added the property `<tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>`

But I still can't start it in tomcat. I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.(WsServerContainer.java:147)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)

Which are because it apparently needs servlet spec 3.1.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, spring-boot also configure websocket support on spring-boot-starter-tomcat, which is includes by spring-boot-starter-web. And according to Apache, you must use Java 7 if you want web socket with Tomcat 7.
Here: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Either compile with Java 7 or exclude websocket support

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```